# how to validate and limit dynamic radio button inside a while loop

Tags: php

I tried to generate radio buttons dynamically from my database, but I am stuck where I need to limit (check if the user selected at least 5 groups(5 different games) of the generated button before submission into the database.

```
<?php while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($query)) : ?>  
    <?php
    $home_team = $row\['home_team'\];
    $away_team = $row\['away_team'\];
    $game_id = $row\['game_id'\];
    $team_joined =  $home_team.' VS '.$away_team;
    $teams =  $home_team.'vs'.$away_team;
    $match_day = @$row\['match_day'\];
    $match_time = @$row\['match_time'\];

    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');
     $time = date('l, jS F h:iA'); 
    ?>
     <?php 
    if (isset($_POST\['submit'\])) {
     $amount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST\['amount'\]);
    $games = @$_POST\[''.$game_id.''\];
    $countGames = count($games);
    echo $countGames;
    /* if ($countGames < 3) {
     $errorfill = "please selecet 3 games";
     } else { */
     if ($amount) {
     foreach ($games as $game) {
    $gameValue = $game;
    if ($amount < $bank_verify) {
    $money_left = $bank_verify - $amount;
     $deduct_query = mysql_query("UPDATE bank SET money_unit='$money_left' WHERE username='$username' ");
    $query_start_game = mysql_query("INSERT INTO bet10_players VALUES('', '$username', '$amount',
                      '$gameValue', '$team_joined', '$game_id','$time', '$pin', '$match_day', '$match_time')") or die(mysql_error());
    header("Location: print.php?pin=$pin&time=$time");
    } else {
    $errorbank = "SORRY!!! You do not have enough units to stake this bet";
    }
    }
    } else {
    $errorfill = "You have not entered any amount";
    }
    //}
    }
    ?>
    <form role="form" action="#" method="post">
    <h5><?php echo $team_joined; ?></h5>
    <h5><?php echo '<span style="color:#f0ad4e;">' . $match_day . ', ' . $match_time . '</span>'; ?></h5>
    <label><input type="radio" name="<?php echo '' . $game_id . '\[' . $game_id . '\]'; ?>" value="<?php echo $home_team; ?>">Home</label>&nbsp;
    <label><input type="radio" name="<?php echo '' . $game_id . '\[' . $game_id . '\]'; ?>" value="Draw ">Draw</label>&nbsp;
    <label><input type="radio" name="<?php echo '' . $game_id . '\[' . $game_id . '\]'; ?>" value="<?php echo $away_team; ?>">Away</label>
    <hr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your amount here">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger"  style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
```

This is the link to the image of what I intend to achieve with these code  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xif8M.png

Comment: Few points here , you shouldn't have to escape your `[` and `]` like you have `\[`. You should not be using `@` to suppress warnings, instead use `isset()` and/or `empty()`. Stop using `mysql_*` funcitions, they are removed as of PHP 7, and finally stop using variables into your sql statements. Those are injection hazards. Research bind parameters. Finally, your question is a bit broad, which part is not working in your code?

Comment: I really appreciate @Rasclatt. I will correct that. Back to the problem, what I ultimately want to achieve is to use an if statement to check whether the user select at least 5 different games from the list of many. I have not been able to do this and it will expose the user to select games below my required target. Also I observe whenever I submit games, each game enter a new row inside the database despite the fact that I used one submit input.

Comment: #Rasclatt, please kindly help me out. Thanks

Comment: Take the form tag that is in the while loop out of the while loop and stick it before the loop starts (should only be 1 open and 1 close tag), move the processing of the post data above the loop and only run once when post is sent, rename the field names something like `game[{ game_id}]` (game_id being the actual ids from your database), then in the post submit, you count the game array to make sure it has at least 5 values.

Comment: Last, you should make a function or two to clean the script up and make it better in terms of expansion and use-ability .

Comment: Hi #Rasclatt. I won't be able to use the following variables if the processing of the former is done above the loop:         <?php
    $home_team = $row\['home_team'\];
    $away_team = $row\['away_team'\];
    $game_id = $row\['game_id'\];
    $team_joined =  $home_team.' VS '.$away_team;
    $teams =  $home_team.'vs'.$away_team;
    $match_day = @$row\['match_day'\];
    $match_time = @$row\['match_time'\];

    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');
     $time = date('l, jS F h:iA'); 
    ?>

Comment: You can, you just have to do it properly. You should not be setting your timezone in a loop, you only need to set it once

Comment: Hi #Rasclatt, I have tried it sir,  still didn't work. Giving me sleepless night and headache since. Could you please help with a sample of how you think it should rightly be? My mail is olukayodefadairo@gmail.com. This aspect is just the last piece of the puzzle to complete my project, but it's making me sweat for the past 2 months. I need somebody to put me through. I have been learning php on my own since the turn of this year. Please somebody should help.

Comment: Are you doing this on your own system or is this a public host?

Comment: If it's public-facing, I can fix it via ftp, it's too much work to try and create tables that might work for your example. The problem is that you have a bunch of issues and I don't see how you are setting some of the settings in your script example.

Answer (score 0):

Because there are a lot of issues just with what you have, I can not actually "fix" what you have in good conscience. The `mysql_*` library is deprecated (removed in >= PHP7) and you are escaping a bunch of things you don't need to, as I noted. Also, as noted, using `@` to silence warnings is not a good idea, you will want to just fix them. If I were to do this, I would have a series of classes that I would create. I would also do an `.htaccess` or `web.config` (Windows) to force everything through the index page, but I suspect from your script you have individual pages, so I will go on that notion:

First off, I would probably create a base app that had some simple, helpful features.

**/vendors/App.php**

```
<?php
class App
    {
        # Easily return post values even if they don't exist without drawing errors
        public  function getPost($key=false)
            {
                if(!empty($key))
                    return (isset($_POST[$key]))? $_POST[$key] : false;

                return $_POST;
            }
        # Easily return session values even if they don't exist without drawing errors
        public  function getSession($key=false)
            {
                if(!empty($key))
                    return (isset($_SESSION[$key]))? $_SESSION[$key] : false;

                return $_SESSION;
            }
        # Used to render pages
        public  function render($file)
            {
                ob_start();
                include($file);
                $data   =   ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                return $data;
            }
    }
```

**/vendors/Game.php**

If you create a base Game class, you will better be able to control Game-related base features

```
<?php
class Game extends App
    {
        protected   $games  =   array();    
        protected   $errors =   array();
        protected   $con;
        # Inject the database
        public  function __construct(\PDO $con)
            {
                $this->con  =   $con;
            }
        # Fetch a list (or just one) game
        public  function gameList($game_id = false)
            {
                $where          =   (!empty($game_id))? " WHERE game_id = '{$game_id}'" : "";
                $this->games    =   array();
                $query          =   $this->con->query("SELECT * FROM games{$where}");
                while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $this->games[]  =   $result;
                }

                return $this;
            }
        # Send back the games if stored
        public  function getGames($first = false)
            {
                # If you you only need one row returned
                if($first)
                    return (isset($this->games[0]))? $this->games[0] : false;
                # Return entire list
                return $this->games;
            }
        # Count how many are currently stored
        public  function getCount()
            {
                return count($this->games);
            }
    }
```

**/vendors/Game/Observer.php**

If you create a base Game Observer class, you will better be able to control listeners and processing of requests.

```
<?php
namespace Game;

class Observer extends \Game
    {
        protected   $time;
        # This is a general listener method, listens for the post
        # It needs work, I don't know where you are getting some of these
        # variables from...I am injecting for example-sake
        public  function listen($bank_verify,$pin,$min=5)
            {
                # Listen for the submission
                if(empty($this->getPost('submit')))
                    return $this;
                elseif(empty($this->getSession('username')))
                    return $this;
                # Fetch the post values, fitler empty
                $REQUEST    =   array_filter($this->getPost('game'));
                # See if there are at least 5 submitted
                if(count($REQUEST) < $min) {
                    $this->errors[] =   'You must have at least '.$min.' selected';
                    return $this;
                }

                foreach($REQUEST as $id => $value) {
                    $this->games[$id]   =   $value;
                }

                $username   =   $this->getSession('username');
                $amount     =   $this->getPost('amount');

                if($amount < $bank_verify) {
                    $money_left = $bank_verify - $amount;
                    $this->updateAccount($money_left,$username);

                    foreach($this->games as $id => $value) {
                        $query_start_game = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO bet10_players VALUES('',?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                        $query_start_game->execute(array(
                            $username,
                            $amount,
                            $gameValue,
                            $team_joined,
                            $game_id,
                            $time,
                            $pin,
                            $match_day,
                            $match_time
                        ));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $this->errors[] =   'Not enough money.';
                    return $this;
                }

                header("Location: print.php?pin=$pin&time=$time");
                exit;
            }
        # This sets the timezone (just once)
        public  function setTime($tz = 'Africa/Lagos')
            {
                date_default_timezone_set($tz);
                $this->time =   date('l, jS F h:iA');
                return $this;
            }
        # This will update the account safely
        public  function updateAccount($money_left,$username)
            {
                $sql    =   "UPDATE bank SET money_unit = ? WHERE username = ?";
                $query  =   $this->con->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute(array($money_left,$username));
                return $query;
            }
        # This probably needs work, but you should insert using this method
        public  function addBets($array,$table='bet10_players')
            {
                $fill   =   "'', ".implode(', ',array_fill(0,count($array),'?'));
                $sql    =   "INSERT INTO `{$table}` VALUES({$fill})";
                $query  =   $this->con->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute($array);
                return $query;
            }
        # Returns the time if need be...
        public  function getTime()
            {
                return $this->time;
            }
    }
```

**/config.php**

I would create this page to be included on all pages at the top. It can be expanded and is good to keep everything consistent like your root path and such.

```
<?php
# start the session
session_start();
# Create some useful defines
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('CLASSES',ROOT_DIR.DS.'vendors');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','databasename');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','');
# Create a class autoloader which turns a \Namespace\Class into a directory
# like /var/html/domain/mydomain/vendor/Namespace/Class.php
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $path   =   str_replace(DS.DS,DS,CLASSES.DS.str_replace('\\',DS,$class).'.php');
    if(is_file($path))
        include_once($path);
});
```

**/index.php**

```
<?php
# Check if we are inside the class, if not, do so
if(!isset($this)) {
    # Include the config file
    require_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');
    # Create your connection (you should expand on this...)
    $con    =   new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
    # Create a Game object
    echo (new \Game\Observer($con))->render(__FILE__);
    # Stop further execution
    exit;
}
# Now we are inside the \Game\Observer class, so you can now use $this
# Set the time and add a listener for post
$this->setTime();
# Since there is no indication of where some of these variables come from,
# this listen method will need attention...actually all the elements from the
# \Game and \Game\Observer need review, but they should be close enough to figure out
$this->listen($bank_verify,$pin);
?>
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <?php
    # $this->gameList()->getGames() should just return an array from your database
    foreach($this->gameList()->getGames() as $row) {
        $team_joined    =   $row['home_team'].' VS '.$row['away_team'];
        $teams          =   $row['home_team'].'vs'.$row['away_team'];
    ?>
    <h5><?php echo $team_joined; ?></h5>
    <h5><span style="color:#f0ad4e;"><?php echo $row['match_day'].', '.$row['match_time'] ?></span></h5>
    <input type="hidden" name="game[<?php echo $row['game_id'] ?>]" value="" />
    <label><input type="radio" name="game[<?php echo $row['game_id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['home_team']; ?>" />Home</label>&nbsp;
    <label><input type="radio" name="game[<?php echo $row['game_id'] ?>]" value="draw" />Draw</label>&nbsp;
    <label><input type="radio" name="game[<?php echo $row['game_id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['away_team']; ?>" />Away</label>
    <hr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your amount here" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger"  style="margin-bottom: 10px;" />
    </div>
</form>
```

When you process the post, you will retrieve data from the database based on the game id, so you should get all the variables you need except for ones that have no indication of origin in your script. Anyway, this is what I would do if I were you. One final note, I have not tested any of this, some of the methods are based off a framework I use, but I think it's a safer version of your script where sql injection is concerned, though you will have to research what some of this is doing...

Comment: Thanks sir #Rasclatt. I really appreciate your effort, but if I'm not gonna deceive myself, I have to confess to you that I am not OOP imclined. I can send the whole code to you via your email(if you wouldn't mind giving me) and also export my mysql table. Thanks #Rasclatt